# Will adding a sequence of consecutive numbers after a sequence of ordered, but non-consecutive numbers, affect the optimization of a switch statement?

Tags: c

I have a switch which has some random numbers: 1,5,16...
Imagine there are 10 or 20 of them.
After them, I have some macros where I can assign my own signed int numbers. So they can be 1000, or 32000...
Imagine there are also 10 or 20 of those.

Now, my question is:

- will ordering and making my numbers consecutive even help with optimization if the former numbers are ordered but not consecutive?
- will using smaller numbers (like 1000, compared to 32000) affect performance in any theoretical way?

Code:

```
switch (x) {
    case 1:
    // stuff
    break; 

    case 5:
    // stuff
    break;

    case 16:
    // stuff
    break;

    case 32000:
    // stuff
    break;

    case 32001:
    // stuff
    break;

    case 32002:
    // stuff
    break;

    defult:
    break;
}
```

If you need hardware specifics, imagine we are talking about the most default theoretical scenario: gcc, intel, no optimizations.

Please advise.

Comment: You mention "theoretical", but you also mention quite a specific setup. What do you really want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your compiler, usually it should not help. Some compiler may implement a binary search, others may implement a if/else chain. But as long as not all of your numbers are consecutive there won't be a jump table*. The order of your case statements does not make a difference.

```
switch (x) {
case 1:
     ...
     break;
case 3:
     ...
     break;
case 5:
     ...
     break;
}
```

and

```
switch (x) {
case 1:
     ...
     break;
case 5:
     ...
     break;
case 3:
     ...
     break;
}
```

Will be (usually) compiled to exactly the same code.

EDIT:

If larger numbers than the type of `x` can handle, the result is undefined. Otherwise it does not make a difference.

*Sometimes it can be worth, for example if there are just gaps between the numbers.

Comment: "But as long as not all of your numbers are consecutive there won't be a jump table. " Says who? :) I did this for a (the first ever, in fact) C compiler for the ARM. I handled the most-of-values are consecutive (allowing for a few gaps) with a jump table + some individual comparisons for a few outlying values. It did a good job on some scenarios, but overall probably wasn't worth the complexity and wouldn't work well on modern memory/cache architectures.

Comment: Ok, you get this one :) But as you said, it is usually not worth it. I should edit to: if the numbers are far apart, there won't be a jump table. And respect for that project.